# Int convert to str using for cycle

Tags: python, python-3.4

why such construction doesn't work?

```
l = [1,2,3]
for x in l:
    x = str(x)
    print(l)
```

it returnes:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

instead of expected:

```
['1', '2', '3']
['1', '2', '3']
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each iteration you're printing the original list without modifying it.

Use [map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

```
 list(map(str, l))
 >> ['1', '2', '3']
```

or a list comprehension

```
l = [str(x) for x in l]
```

Comment: you need `list(map..)` for python3

Answer (score 0):

When you do `x = str(x)` it changes the value in `x` to `str` (and not the element in your list `l`)

But as you are trying to change the list `l`

I suggest you try a list comprehension:

`l = [str(x) for x in l]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to store back the casted x back to the list as below:

```
l = [1,2,3]
new_l = []
for x in l:
    new_l.append(str(x))
    print(new_l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also,if you're not accustomed with map (see other answers) you could use :

```
for i,x in enumerate(l):
    l[i] = str(x)
```

But other answers are just better.